# How to use an external dataTable in Cucumber?

Tags: java, datatable, cucumber, bdd

I'm using Cucumber and Java to write BDD tests.

I wanted to migrate from usung datatables in feature files, because I have a lot of fields and it's dublicated for a few steps, to using link to the table with values.
From this one approach:

```
GIVEN I created account with
| name | type  |
| test | basic |
```

to the approach:

```
GIVEN I created account with account.table
```

account.table file has value:

```
| name | type  |
| test | basic |
```

I don't know how to parse 'path to the file with dataTable' to the actual 'dataTable'.
I tried write step like this:

```
@GIVEN("^I created account with \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void createAccount(DataTable dataTable) { ... }
```

But it's not working. Because there are no automatic convertion from path to file to dataTable.
Here's the error:

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Don't know how to convert
> "resources\testdata\account.table" into cucumber.api.DataTable. Try
> writing your own converter:
> @cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamConverter(DataTableConverter.class)

Is there any examples of parsing it or any ideas?

Comment: I think you can use the table name as String in cucumber step and in step definition you can access that table from external path and compete the required operations.

Comment: But how parse file to dataTable? It's parsed automatically for the first approach.

Comment: It worked for first approach because its an inbuilt functionality of cucumber. But you are looking for something different. For that what you can do pass the table name as string in step and in step definition by using that `String argument` write program to read data from `.table` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it with following code, but wanted something easy and out of Cucumber box itself:

```
public void readFromExternalTable(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = readLinesFromFile(fileName);
        List<String> headers = getColumnsFromRow(lines.get(0));
        List<String> values = getColumnsFromRow(lines.get(1));
        DataTable table = createTable(headers, values);
    }

static List<String> readLinesFromFile(String fileName) {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;
        while ((line =  reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines;
}

static List<String> getColumnsFromRow(String line) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] row  = line.split("\\|");
    for (int i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
        list.add(row[i].trim());
    }
    return list;
}

static <String> DataTable createTable(List<String> headers, List<String> values) {
    List<List<String>> rawTable = new ArrayList<>();
    rawTable.add(headers);
    rawTable.add(values);
    return DataTable.create(rawTable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take external test data benefit and many more with [QAF-BDD2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html). It has [inbuilt data-providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#in-built-data-providers) and supports custom data provider as well. Below example is to provide data from CSV.

```
@dataFile:resources/data/newuser.csv
Scenario: create new user
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about it. And I also could swich to JBehave, because it also have native support of external dataTable, but on my project I have strict limitations to use only Cucumber without addons.